# Python unexpected EOF while parsing 4

Tags: python

So i'm doing image parsing right now and having an awful time of it.

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import turtle
import drawing

# define a location for our file
url = 'http://i5.nyu.edu/~cmk380/pythondata/'

# open a connection to the URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# read data from URL as a string
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')

image = input('Enter an image filname:')

newurl = url+image+'.txt'

if int(image[5]) <= 0:
    print('Sorry,',newurl,'doesn\'t exist.')

else:
    print('Success!  I was able to find ',newurl)

# define a location for our file
newurl2 = newurl

# open a connection to the URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen(newurl2)

# read data from URL as a string
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')

#obtain data
print(data)

#turn data into a string and convert to float
string = data
splitstring = string.split(',')

splitstring[0]=float(splitstring[0])
splitstring[1]=float(splitstring[1])
splitstring[2]=float(splitstring[2])


for index in range (4,len(splitstring)):
    if splitstring[index] == 'b':
        print('\n')

    else:
        drawing.draw_box(float(splitstring[0]),float(splitstring[1],float(splitstring[2]), float(splitstring[index]), float(splitstring[index]), float(splitstring[index])
```

And this is my function:

```
# draw a box at position x, y
# width and height will be w & h
# r, g and b will be the color
def draw_box(x, y, w, h, r, g, b):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.pencolor(float(r), float(g), float(b))
    turtle.fillcolor(float(r),float(g),float(b))
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for x in range(4):
        turtle.forward(w)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

The problem arises right at the end of the program and I have been fiddling with it for ages. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last call to `drawing.draw_box` your parentheses aren't closed. So it's hitting the end of the file while looking for the end of the function call.

Also the second value passed isn't closed, `float(splitstring[1]` <--